# R not reading all rows of my data

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, import

Here is my code:

```
df <- read.table(file.choose(), 
                 sep = "\t",
                 skip = 2,
                 fill = T)
```

Here is the file that in excel: https://ufile.io/q1xvg
and here it is in txt file that I use specifically import (excel saved as txt): https://ufile.io/8vnu6

The data has over 3000 rows but RStudio only imports `1483 obs. of 24 variables` as seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aeywf.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `read.delim`:

```
df <- read.delim("2016-txt.tsv", sep = "\t", skip = 2);
dim(df);
#[1] 3312   24
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you help me understand what the problem was with `read.table`?

Comment: @kindofhungry No worries, glad to help. `read.delim` is really just a wrapper function around `read.table` that sets certain function arguments (you can check by e.g. executing `read.delim` in an R session). In your particular case, the critical arguments are `fill = TRUE, quote = "\""` to account for missing and quoted entries. `read.table` works as well if you explicitly add these function arguments. Because of that `read.delim` is sometimes more "forgiving" than `read.table`.

Comment: PS. You might also consider reading the excel file directly. Have a look at the excellent `readxl` package. In that case you can do directly `require(readxl); df <- read_excel("2016.xlsx");`.